# Apache2 does not redirect correctly

Tags: apache-2.4

I have Apache2 running on my Debian Jessie Server. I have a VirtualHost listening on port 80 which should redirect to port 443 because that one has SSL enabled.
This works fine if you just type in the basic URL, but if you want to go directly to a subdirectory, e.g.:

`http://www.example.com`**`/foo/bar`**

the first slash is missed out after the browser gets redirected which transforms the URL into something like this:

`https://www.example.com`**`foo/bar`**

which of course leads to a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is my configuration for port 80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    [...]
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have a DNS A record set up for `https://www.example.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be missing a trailing slash <kbd>/</kbd> after your domainname :

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
```

should be:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: That worked fine. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check for .htaccess files that might be rewriting the request in unintended ways. Any .htaccess file in the path to your document root could cause that.